# Different compilation behavior with type cast between eclipse and maven

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

Here is my code example:

```
private static void fac(Map<? extends Serializable,? extends Serializable> mapTo){
    //do sth.
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,Object> mapFrom=null;
    fac((Map<? extends Serializable, ? extends Serializable>) mapFrom);     
}
```

The code above is compiled successfully in eclipse(with a type safety warning) but failed in maven(an "incompatible types" error caused by javac?).

Now I have to change my code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,Object> mapFrom=null;
    fac((Map) mapFrom);     
}
```

I've confirmed the java version is the same, and my question is:

1. Why do they have different behavior?
2. What's the preferred way to write the code?

Comment: what's the error in maven?

Comment: It could be that they're compiling for different versions of Java? As Ian said, we need all the details.

Comment: @EvanKnowles I'm sure java version is the same.

Comment: @IanGil Sorry, it's an "incompatible types" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse comes with its own Java compiler; Maven uses `javac`. Most of the time, both accept the same code but generics are complicated and compiler do have bugs. There are a couple of known bugs in `javac` of Java 6 which cause problems, for example.

Oracle will not fix them. The solution is to use Java 7 to run Maven and configure the `maven-compiler-plugin` the generate Java 6 byte code (see [Kumar Sambhav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19267547/34088)).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this plugin (inside build->plugins-> tag) to your pom.xml :-

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This will ensure the compiler version to be used with your project.

Comment: I have similar config in my pom.xml(with properties)