# Why maven fails at build and not Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have written this code in Eclipse (JDK 8.0.20) is compilation JDK.

```
this.invokeMethod( (Set<MyClass<?>>) vari);

private void invokeMethod(Set<MyClass<?>> vari) throws  Exception{
         // TODO
}
```

In eclipse Everything looks well. But when I build it with maven, I have error:

```
[ERROR] /Path/Test.java:[52,88] incompatible types: java.util.Set<capture#1 of ? extends x.y.z.MyClass<?>> cannot be converted to java.util.Set<x.y.z.MyClass<?>>
```

Comment: Do you use the same jdk with maven and eclipse?

Comment: Please refer to this [post][1].  Hope it helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266797/different-compilation-behavior-with-type-cast-between-eclipse-and-maven

Comment: Which version of the `maven-compiler-plugin` are you using? What's the setting of your environment variable `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: JAVA HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31
plugin: 3.2.
MVN: 3.2

Comment: In netbenas there is error too. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add those two lines in your pom and check if maven succeeds in compiling:

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>  
</properties>
```

Comment: This does not helped me :(
might be this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266797/different-compilation-behavior-with-type-cast-between-eclipse-and-maven